# Strange Behaviour of Bevel

Tags: bevel

I hope that someone can help a newb
In my learning project, I got a mirror modifier active.
Then I added some cubes and played with them.
To learn something about cylinders I added one - yes first-time shortcut used correctly.
I marked the top vertices and added a bevel modifier via "CRTL + B"
When I try to morph a sphere, the situation in the screenshot appears.
For me, it Looks like I got 2 "Centers" or something but I don't know how that can be fixed.
Already tried to delete the cylinder and add a new one, tried to work with additional loop cuts but Nothing helped :-(  [image: Bevel with 2 centers]

---

1. In *Edit Mode* setup *Mirror Modifier* in Y and Z.
2. Add a cylinder on world origin
3. Scale the cylinder
4. Add the bevel and try to round up the upper half of the cylinder to
   a spherical shape

Then I took the object and moved it to make the screenshot. So, bevel was used at starting Point!

This is the result:

[image: strange behavior of bevel at starting point]

The result I would describe as the bevel tries to move each of the vertices and not only the top ones (the result of experiment see last rows of that comment) but all the vertex all around the wall of the cylinder. It seems that the Vector of moving is straight to Y-axis

I tried that again while only marking the top vertex - doesn't help to get the Right result

26.6.2020
Additional Information as requested
I added an image of what I want to do.
Take a cylinder, add a bevel at the top, move the bevel straight up to get a spherical top.

This Image was created in a new model but it doesn't work in my target model.

Yes, I tried and deactivated the Mirror modifier and the result is the same.

I tried all <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  Points for the Cursor but it has not solved my problem

[image: eCylinder to cylinder with spere top]

Comment: Make sure your 3D Cursor is at the center of the World space. Select the strange, doubled up object in Object Mode. Right click on that object, and from the menu, choose Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor. What happens? I expect that what happens is that your object straightens itself out and stops being doubled up. This is because its origin is not currently at the World space center, yet it's still mirroring, due to the mirror modifier. But the modifier has a different mirroring center than the object has a local center. So it mirrors from a non-local center, and creates this doubling effect.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
Edit mode: Delete Cylinder
Switch to object mode: Add Cylinder
object mode: Scale Cylinder up
Switch to Edit mode: bevel